# A question on Lebesgue measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a Lebesgue measurable function, and define a function $\phi:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $\phi(x,y):=f(x-y)$.  I want to prove that $\phi$ is Lebesgue measurable, *i.e.*, given an open set $\mathcal{O}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, $\phi^{-1}\left[\mathcal{O}\right]\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ is Lebesgue measurable.  I first attempted to take advantage of the fact that the function $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x,y):=x-y$ is continuous, as here $\phi=f\circ g$.  However, this approach failed, as the composition is in the wrong order; the continuous function $g$ is on the inside, so $\phi^{-1}\left[\mathcal{O}\right]=\left(f\circ g\right)^{-1}\left[\mathcal{O}\right]=g^{-1}\left[f^{-1}\left[\mathcal{O}\right]\right]$, which is not helpful, as the preimage of a Lebesgue measurable set under a continuous function need not be Lebesgue measurable.  My next attempt involved taking $\mathcal{O}$ to be a basic open interval of the form $\left(a,b\right)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and considering $\phi^{-1}\left[\mathcal{O}\right]$ directly, but I have as yet been unable to determine the nature of $\phi^{-1}\left[\mathcal{O}\right]$.  I’m not sure whether I’m on the right track or not here, so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(x,y)=x-y$ and A be a Lebesgue measurable set, $g^{-1}(A)$ is a rectangle for the axes $\{(1,1),(-1,1) \}$ since it can be written as 
$$ g^{-1}(A) = \{ (a/2,-a/2): a \in A \}  \times \{ (x,y): x = y \}.    $$
Thus, $g^{-1} \circ f^{-1} \mathcal O $ is Lebesgue measurable if $f^{-1} \mathcal O$ is, which is true if $\mathcal O$ is open.

Answer (score 0):

Continuous implies Lebesgue-mesurable and the composition of two mesurable functions is mesurable.

Comment: The problem is the definition of Lebesgue-measurable function: a function $f$ is Lebesgue-measurable if the pre-image of every Borel set is Lebesgue-measurable (but not necessarily Borel): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function

Comment: I have another idea:  show that the preimage of a Lebesgue measurable set under _this particular_ continuous function will be Lebesgue measurable, probably using the $\varepsilon$-$\mathcal{O}$ definition for $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Ok my bad I thought that every Borel set was Lebesgue mesurable (you can't be sure of anything...). But isn't it
$$ (f \circ g)^{-1} \mathcal O = f^{-1} \circ g^{-1} \mathcal O   $$

Comment: Yeah, every Borel set is Lebesgue measurable, but not every Lebesgue measurable set is Borel.

Comment: No, taking the inverse image of a composite map reverses the order of the composition.

Comment: It’s an algebraic thing (my kind of thing):  $\left(gh\right)^{-1}=h^{-1}g^{-1}$.

Comment: yes ok I needed to write it down. Just out of curiosity, can you give an example of a Lebesgue mesurable set that is not Borel?

Comment: Let $\psi(x)=\varphi(x)+x,x\in\left[0,1\right]$, where $\varphi$ is the Cantor function.  Let $K$ denote the Cantor set.  According to Vitali's Theorem, $\psi\left[K\right]$ contains a subset $W$ that is nonmeasurable.  However, the set $\psi^{-1}\left[W\right]$ is measurable and of measure zero, as it is a subset of the Cantor set.  Hence $A:=\psi^{-1}\left[W\right]$ is measurable, but not Borel, since if it were, its image under $\psi$ would also be Borel, since $\psi$ is strictly increasing and continuous.